What is the point of the "many machines on Ix" conversation?
In David Lynch's 1984 Dune adaptation, the opening scene has the following dialogue:

Guild Navigator: We have just folded space from Ix.
Padishah Emperor Shaddam IV: Yes? How was your journey?
Guild Navigator: Many machines on Ix, new machines.
Padishah Emperor Shaddam IV: Oh, yes?
Guild Navigator: Not as good as those on Richese.

This dialogue (and the meeting itself) are not in the book. The line "many machines on Ix, new machines" is catchy, memorable and often quoted, but why was it added? What does this exchange mean? It's off-topic from the rest of their conversation, the Emperor seems bored by it, and neither Ix nor Richese play any major role in the first book of Dune.

I'd suspect this is the moral equivalent of Star Trek technobabble. "Captain,  the derelict alien ship is picking up dangerous levels of baryons..."

It's probably a sort of easter egg, i.e. name dropping to indicate that somebody involved with the movie had actually read the book which, frankly, otherwise would not have been really obvious.

It's a very condensed info-dump.

"We know the Ixians are up to something."

Regardless of importance, this is one of many things Lynch's Dune did that are amazing (regardless of its other flaws). The Guild Navigators are myserious and bizarre in his vision. A shame the otherwise good Villeneuve version barely mentioned navigators.

Since I have no evidence this isn't an answer but I it's possible this was to at least mention Ix in the event that there would be films made based on the subsequent books.  These, and much more so the Tleilaxu, were supposed to be a significant power and it was somewhat jarring, almost retconn-y, in subsequent books that they were so important but not mentioned at all in Dune.

I have a clear memory about this scene, which I believe comes from The Dune Storybook, a junior photonovelization. Unfortunately I can't verify my recollection against the source.
As I recall, we see this scene from Shaddam's point of view, and his thoughts are preoccupied with how strange and out of the ordinary the Guild's visit is, how little idea he has as to what they want or what their motives are, and how much he's having to read into every crumb of information they give him. At this point, his thoughts as we hear them are "is the Guild trying to hint that Ix is flouting the Butlerian Jihad and the proscription on Thinking Machines?".
Of course, the content of an adaptation like that doesn't necessarily reflect privileged insight to the intent of the creators of the film, and the author may have been trying to make sense of the scene based on her knowledge of the book just like we are.
More speculatively, an exchange like this - a seemingly innocent observation that can be read into by the recipient without the speaker technically stating anything actionable - is a standard thing in politics and intrigue, and especially relevant to a setting like Dune where Truthsayers make it important to pay very careful attention to exactly what you can testify to as technically true. In that context, it's the sort of thing you'd expect such powerful people to drop into conversation, and the emperor's "boredom" can be read as confusion as to what the Navigator is actually getting at.
I note as well that the Navigator's next line is "you are transparent - I see many things". Although not stated, that could suggest another standard trope in play - "I'm testing you with probing comments to see how you react, and using your responses to draw conclusions about something totally unrelated". The Navigator could be planting ideas in Shaddam's head that affect his possible future actions, and thus the possible futures the Navigator can perceive. Or more simply, he may just be verifying that "the emperor isn't concerned with Ix right now, which rules out one set of theories we had about what's going on. Time to ask him directly".
As to why this dialogue specifically and its topic were chosen for the scene, I can only speculate, but the fact that it refers to something otherwise entirely unrelated to the plot of the movie is arguably a strength, in that it contributes to the sense of a larger setting with a lot going on outside of the core players and conflict in focus. When a story is too tightly zoomed in on only the moving parts relevant to its own action, it can become claustrophobic.

I can't see that scene you're referring to; https://i.sstatic.net/V0K8CYvt.png - https://i.sstatic.net/0k3moSUC.png. Are you sure it's in the Dune Storybook?

No, I'm not - it was just the likeliest candidate I could think of for where I'd have read the perspective I remember, that isn't the movie or original book.
